# Authenticating to SharePoint Client Context WITHOUT Username or Password?

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

In C#, I'm accessing the SharePoint site context to upload files using a username and password:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(tenantAdminUrl))
            {
                //Provide count and pwd for connecting to the source
                var passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], passWord);

                ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

This works fine. But the client does not want to use a designated account for this. Is there a way to use a client ID and client secret to Authenticate?

I am not finding much, if any, documentation about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Probably not - `ClientContext` always needs some credentials.

Long answer:
The `ClientContext` can be authenticatd using some kind of tokens. Search for OAuth/apps/add-in in combination with SharePoint. A starting-point could be [this article by Krik Evans](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/04/05/inside-sharepoint-2013-oauth-context-tokens/) or [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/09/24/introducing-sharepointcontext-for-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps/).

But I'm guessing you'd need add-in-infrastucture for this (i.e. user accesses SharePoint, from there he is redirected to your add-in - the redirect has all the tokens needed as query-params, your add-in can leverage `TokenHelper` or `SharePointContextProvider` to create an authenticated `ClientContext`)